# Can't read data from SQL Server database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I'm having a problem when I'm reading data from a SQL Server database. The main thing is that I want to read the data from the database and display the data in a Label control. But the concern is that it can't read data to it. I will show you the code snippet and any comments/suggestions are gladly considered.

```
Option Explicit On

Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Partial Class ViewDetail
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim con As OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
    Dim InstructorID As Integer

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    InstructorID = Request.QueryString("Instructor_ID")
    Integer.TryParse(lblID.Text, InstructorID)
    con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=ARIES-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=SchoolDB")
    con.Open()
    cmd = New OleDbCommand("SelectData", con)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", InstructorID)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If dr.HasRows Then
        While dr.Read
            lblID.Text = dr("Instructor_ID").ToString
            lblFirstname.Text = dr("FirstName").ToString
            lblLastname.Text = dr("LastName").ToString
            lblAddress.Text = dr("Address").ToString
            lblContact.Text = dr("Contact_Number").ToString
        End While
    End If
    dr.Close()
    cmd.Dispose()
    con.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You don't explain what is the error. Do you get an exception? If yes what is the error message?

Comment: You have not mentioned that exactly where you are getting issue. is it not opening connection? or error giving at ExecuteReader?? provide more detail so someone can help you better.

Comment: Following `dr = cmd.ExecuteReader` should be `dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()`

Comment: there is no error.. there is a bug where in the data in the database is not displaying in the Label control..

Comment: `.ToString` should be `ToString()` isn't it ?

Comment: @Leopard VB.NET allows both forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line seems to be totally wrong

```
Integer.TryParse(lblID.Text, InstructorID)
```

This lines takes the current value in the `lblID.Text`  at the Page_Load event and tries to set the value of `InstructorID`. But your code seems to want this value from the `QueryString` passed that contains the real value.

If you are certain the the QueryString contains a valid integer then remove that line and add

```
InstructorID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString("Instructor_ID"))
```

Comment: Glad to be of help. By the way I suggest to use the native SqlClient class libraries instead of the OleDb when working with Sql Server